# SQL - How do I create a SELECT with formatted name

Tags: sql, select

I have the table:

```
ID, firstname, lastname, companyName, isCompany
```

How do I run a query such that I can do:

```
SELECT ID, name FROM myTable ...
```

where the name is an algorithm along the lines of

```
if(isCompany)
  name = companyName
else
  name = "lastname, firstname"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't state your DBMS but this is ANSI SQL:

```
select id,
       case
         when is_company then companyName
         else lastname||', '||firstname
       end as name
from my_table
```

This assumes that `is_company` is of type `boolean`